# Storing large quantities of potassium salts: nuclear radiation

Tags: radioactivity, gamma-rays

Assuming I store $300 \;\text{kg}$ of potassium hydroxide in plastic bags on a palette in my living room.

This is equivalent to $5347 \;\text{mol}$ of potassium content or roughly $0.626 \;\text{mol}$ of K-40 ($24.5 \;\text{g}$). Assuming an activity of $31.6 \;\text{Bq/g}$ for naturally-occurring potassium, this corresponds to a total activity of $6.61 \;\text{MBq}$. In $10.72 \;\%$ of decay events, a gamma ray of $1.46 \;\text{MeV}$ is released (electron capture). $0.1072 \cdot 1.46 \;\text{MeV} \cdot 6.61 \;\text{MBq} = 0.596 \;\text{mJ/h}$. Dividing by a body mass of $75 \;\text{kg}$, I think that the dose rate should be $7.95 \;\text{µSv/h}$.

Is this any kind of legitimate view? I had the chance to measure the activity of $300 \;\text{kg}$ of KOH and found $2.2 \;\text{µSv/h}$ (proportional counter). I think that some kind of absorption cross-section must be introduced as my body of $75 \;\text{kg}$ (or: the measuring probe) does not absorb all of the circularly emitted $\gamma$ radiation. Are you aware of any safety regulations regarding the storage of large quantities of potassium salts?

Comment: So all of the gammas get out of the 300kg of material, and all heads towards your body and your body alone?

Comment: @Jon Custer: Please consider reading my question entirely before commenting in a precociously manner.

Comment: From Wikipedia: “Potassium hydroxide and its solutions are severe irritants to skin and other tissue”. The biggest safety concern with storing 300 kg of KOH in your living room is *not* radioactivity.

Comment: @tstone-1 there isn't anything precocious about Jons comment, you've failed to take into account that the gammas are randomly emitted in the space around the pallet and not directed in a straight line towards the body.

Comment: @Triatticus: This is _exactement_ what is meant by the second-to-last sentence of my question's last paragraph. I will now stop commenting here, just a short note: I've never experienced such a shameful discussion culture as here. I accept that my question is regarded as off-topic, but three of the comments made testify to a lack of reading comprehension and a desire for arrogant verbal attacks.

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on the country you are living in.  Probably best to store it in a shed or garage, for safety, until you find out more.